How to fix this jump effect after the text animation?
In the given example, the jump appears small; however, in my project, with larger font sizes and different fonts, this issue becomes more pronounced. After the animation completes and the new text appears, the text jumps as if it is reverting to its original position.I created Codepen projekt for it as well.
Javascirpt
import SplitType from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/split-type@0.3.1";
import gsap from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/gsap@3.12.5";

function animateWords() {

  const words = ["word1","word2","word3"]

  let currentIndex = 0
  let split
  const textElement = document.querySelector('.primary-h1 span')

  function updateText() {
    textElement.textContent = words[currentIndex]
    split = new SplitType(textElement, {type: 'lines' })
    animateChars(split.chars)
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % words.length
  }

  function animateChars(chars) {
    gsap.from(chars, {
      yPercent: 100,
      stagger: 0.03,
      duration: 1,
      ease: 'power4.out',
      rotate:10,
      onComplete: () => {
        if (split) {
          split.revert();
        }
      }
    })
  }

  setInterval(updateText, 3000)

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    

  animateWords()
  
  
})

HTML
<main class="hero">
      <div class="left layout-ws">
        <h1>
          <div class="mask primary-h1">
            <span>word</span>
          </div>
          <div class="mask">
            <span>randomtext</span>
          </div>
        </h1>
      </div>
</main>

CSS
main {

  .left {
    align-self:last baseline;
    flex: 1;
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;

    h1 {
      font-size: clamp(10rem, 17vw, 10rem);
      align-self:last baseline;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
  
.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layout-ws {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: clamp(16px, 5%, 30px); /* Adjust for fluid side margins */

}


But what exactly would you like to achieve?

I'd like to avoid the jump after the new word appears. As you can see, once the new word appears, it jumps again. The jump is not as noticeable in the CodePen example, but it is much more noticeable with other fonts and it really disrupts the animation.  @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz

This is very difficult to diagnose if it is not visible on Codepen. Because the term "jump" can cover many events. Maybe try making a gif or something similar...

I updated it to another font, and now I hope the problem is more noticeable. It's as if the spacing between the letters keeps changing. @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz

This issue is described in documentation.

Important: The following style should be applied to all target
elements. This prevents the characters from shifting slightly when
text is split/reverted.
.target {   font-kerning: none; } Also, if the target elements are
inside a flex container, they need to have a defined width to prevent
the text from moving when it gets split.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-type#splitting-text
Set:
.layout-ws {
  width: 100%;
  font-kerning: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: clamp(16px, 5%, 30px); /* Adjust for fluid side margins */
}

